# Property file resets after loading

Tags: java, file, properties

I want to add some values to an existing property file, but the file resets everytime I run the program and only the new values are in the file.

I know there are many people with the same problem out there, but I looked at solutions on the internet and nothing worked for me. Many solutions said that you have to call `.load()` before setting properties and storing, but it's seems that calling `.load()` doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
public class FxCheckLocalisation {
    private final File       notFoundPropertiesFile        = new File(
            "C:\\Projekte\\core8\\remote\\src\\main\\resources\\lang\\de\\core_missing_localisation.properties");
    private final Properties notFoundProperties            = new Properties();

    private final File       newLocalisationPropertiesFile = new File(
            "C:\\Projekte\\core8\\remote\\src\\main\\resources\\lang\\de\\core_masks.properties");
    private final Properties newLocalisationProperties     = new Properties();

    private final File       oldLocalisationPropertiesFile = new File(
            "C:\\Projekte\\core8\\remote\\src\\main\\resources\\lang\\de\\core_old.properties");
    private final Properties oldLocalisationProperties     = new Properties();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final FxCheckLocalisation checkLocalisation = new FxCheckLocalisation();

        checkLocalisation.checkProperties();
    }

    private void checkProperties() {
        try (FileInputStream fileReaderNotFound = new FileInputStream(this.notFoundPropertiesFile);
                FileInputStream fileReaderOld = new FileInputStream(this.oldLocalisationPropertiesFile);
                FileInputStream fileReaderNew = new FileInputStream(this.newLocalisationPropertiesFile)) {
            this.notFoundProperties.load(fileReaderNotFound);
            this.oldLocalisationProperties.load(fileReaderOld);
            this.newLocalisationProperties.load(fileReaderNew);

            this.notFoundProperties.forEach((keyNotFound, valueNotFound) -> {
                if ((this.oldLocalisationProperties.getProperty(keyNotFound.toString()) != null)
                        && (this.newLocalisationProperties.getProperty(keyNotFound.toString()) == null)) {
                    this.newLocalisationProperties.setProperty(keyNotFound.toString(),
                            this.oldLocalisationProperties.getProperty(keyNotFound.toString()));
                }
            });

            final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.newLocalisationPropertiesFile);
            this.newLocalisationProperties.store(outputStream, null);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code cycles trough all not found properties and searches them inside oldLocalisationProperties. If it exists it adds this property to newLocalisationProperties.

Can anyone help me and tell me why my file resets everytime and only the new values are shown. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need all this. Just construct them in the appropriate order with the previous one (if any) as the defaults for the current one.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: I believe they are saying you should take advantage of [property defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Properties)). From the Javadoc: "_A property list can contain another property list as its "defaults"; this second property list is searched if the property key is not found in the original property list_".

Comment: It's all in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Properties)). Have a look.

Comment: By the way, this is wrong: `private final File notFoundPropertiesFile  = new File("C:\\Projekte\\core8\\remote\\src\\main\\resources\\lang\\de\\core_missing_localisation.properties");`. For two reasons: 1) That location will not exist once you deploy your application; 2) Resources are not files. You should be accessing resources via methods such as `Class#getResource[AsStream](String)`.